# How to align code vertically and horizontally?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am writing this code, but my code isn't automatically aligning vertically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quantity"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**How the output should look like:**

```
Quantity
0
```

**While it is showing:**

```
Quantity0
```

Comment: Use  Ctrl+Alt+L command when your layout file is open

Answer (score 0):

Note that you've not set the `orientation` in the `LinerLayout`, change that to this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

As the default orientation is `horizontal`, both your `TextView`s are in the same line.

Once you set the orientation to be vertical, it will look like this:

```
Quantity
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<Space/>` tag to add space between views, or you can adjust by mentioning margin and padding as well. But space will be a good option as you don't need to have a concern while RTL and LTR layouts in app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quantity"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="4dp"    // change according to your need.
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be adding space at the end in **Quantity** `TextView`, that means your code will be:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quantity "/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can add `orientation` attribute to `LinearLayout` then set orientation `vertical` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_orientation="vertical">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Quantity"/>

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

If you don't set orientation, in XML by default orientation of `LinearLayout` is `horizontal`. So,If you need vertical views in `LinearLayout` then set orientation attribute as `vertical`.